# Wrong variable value in onClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am duplicating my linear layout dynamically and I have to set onClickListeners for buttons inside the linear layout.

```
for(int i = 0; i <10 ; i++){

   // other code here

   Button approve_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rent_number_up_btn);
   approve_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          approve_btn.setText(String.valueOf(i));
       }
   });
}
```

Everything works fine except that my button's text is always set to 9. I think that's because when the listener is called the value of i is 9 at that time. What I want the value of i at the time the button's listener is set and I am not sure how to do that.

How can I solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but please explain more about your question. I didnot understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting click listener to the same button (by calling `findViewById()`) 10 times in a row. You get the value `9` because thats the last click listener which you added to the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i <10 ; i++){

       // other code here

               Button button = new Button(<Activity Instance>);
            button.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

       approve_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
              approve_btn.setText(String.valueOf(i));
           }
       });

    }
```

In above code you need to add those buttons in your linearlayout.

Hope this will help you,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do but:

Like @Shaishav said your are using same button (R.id.rent_number_up_btn) and your are replacing the click listeners on top of each other. The last value (of the your counter "i")  before your loop finish is 9 , that's why it show 9 all the time. If you want to add 10 buttons inside your  Linear layout just create new Button(context) every time when your loop starts and add this button to your layout via

```
yourLinearlayout.addView(yourNewButton);
```

Then if you set click listener to your new button maybe it will show different values :)